# Silverlight C# - How to hold loop progress until an event completes?

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to loop through the text in a textbox by word in order to spellcheck it. I've split the contents of the textbox into an array, and loop through each word in the array and run it through the spellchecker. When a misspelling is found, I have a popup with a listbox inside it display so that you can choose the correction.

The issue that I'm having, is that it just loops through the whole array and only ends up showing the last correction that needs to be done.

How do I pause the loop so that it waits for a selection to be made and then resume?

Here's the code for the loop:

```
  foreach(string checkedWord in articleWords)
        {
            bool success = _spellChecker.CheckWord(checkedWord);
            List<string> suggest;

            if (!success)
            {
                suggest = _spellChecker.GetSuggestions(checkedWord);
                SpellChecklistBox.Items.Clear();

                foreach (string s in suggest)
                {

                   SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = s });

                }
                SpellCheckerPopup.IsOpen = true;
                SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "          ----------------------" });
                SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "Ignore" });
            }


        }
```

When the SpellCheckerPopup displays, I have an event trigger in the listbox on SelectionChange.

Basically, I need to pause the loop somehow, and then when the SelectionChange event does it's thing, have the loop resume.

Thanks in advance!

-Sootah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding, currently you are going to:

(1) Check each word in the loop

(2) *Pause* the loop when an error is found and pop up a suggestion window

(3) User select a suggestion word and *resume* the loop

I think it's better and easier if the solution is:

(1) Check the word from the first one

(2) Quit the check method with an error flag, and store the position in a variable, pop up a suggestion window

(3) User selects a suggestion word and when User has confirmed the suggestion(e.g. pressing OK on the suggestion window), start the CheckWordMethod again from the stored position

(4) Until step (2) quits with no error flag, which means all words are correct now (but make sure in the whole progress, users can only modify the words by your suggestion window)

Answer (score 0):

**@The Smartest**: Your answer lead me in the correct direction; actually ended up learning a new datatype out of it! Never used a Queue before. (Which made it a *HELL* of a lot simpler than having to track where in the array I was at, as I first figured I thought I'd have to.. :)

Anyway, I'll accept your answer, but here's the code I ended up doing: (The actual replacing of the word in the textbox I've not implemented yet.)

```
private void btnSpelling_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SpellChecklistBox.Items.Clear();

        string[] articleWordsArray = txtArticle.Text.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in articleWordsArray)
        {
            articleWords.Enqueue(word);

        }

        CorrectWord();


    }

private void SpellChecklistBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpellCheckerPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }

private void SpellCheckerPopup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CorrectWord();
        SpellChecklistBox.Items.Clear();
    }

Queue<string> articleWords = new Queue<string>();


    private void CorrectWord()
    {
        if (articleWords.Count() > 0)
        {
            string checkedWord = articleWords.Dequeue();
            bool success = _spellChecker.CheckWord(checkedWord);
            List<string> suggest;

            if (!success)
            {
                suggest = _spellChecker.GetSuggestions(checkedWord);


                foreach (string s in suggest)
                {
                    SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = s });
                }

                SpellCheckerPopup.IsOpen = true;
                SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "          ----------------------" });
                SpellChecklistBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "Ignore" });
                SpellCheckerPopup.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's all pretty straight forward courtesy of the `Queue` datatype. When the spelling button gets clicked it loads the TextBox into an array, and then I loop through the array to enqueue the items into the articleWords queue, after which it calls CorrectWord(). CorrectWord() then loads the relevant list after dequeueing from articleWords, and on the PopUp. Closed event it clears the ListBox and calls CorrectWord() which will keep bringing back the PopUp until there are no more words to be corrected. :)